# How do i save the text that i write in the <input> tag?

Tags: html

How do I save what I write on the

```
<input type='text'>
```

tag, will I need a database or it can be done so that it saves to the file?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<input type='text'>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Anything is possible. What languages are you using?

Comment: well, you could do it either ways. but database is what you need where you have structured data. use php as server programming language and mysql as the DBMS

Comment: Once rendered in browser, strict html is agnostic of where it came from. You would need either a form element with a server url or some javascript to send the data somewhere to be saved. There are many books and tutorials out there that can get you started.

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` is used to collect information from the user. `<input = "text">` is not a valid statement. If you were trying to set a value to the text field then you use 'value' `<input type='text' value='some text'>`. And remember, `<input>` should always be inside `<form>` tag so you can collect the information. And you should use PHP to handle this kind of request. Read about it in [here (w3schools)](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp).

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is :

The input is given is in .html file which is static (can not store any data).

You can save the input value in two ways:

1) You can change the file to .php and save in database.

2) You can export the input to a file and save as a text.

Check the below code to export the text input to txt format.

```
<style>
    form * {
      display: block;
      margin: 10px;

    }

</style>

<script language="Javascript" >

    function download(filename, text) {

      var pom = document.createElement('a');
      pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + 

    encodeURIComponent(text));
      pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

      pom.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(pom);

      pom.click();

      document.body.removeChild(pom);
    }
</script>
```

```
<form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter your file name" required>
    <textarea rows=3 cols=50 name="text"> Type your text here and click SAVE. </textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE">          
</form>
```

Comment: Hope this answer helped!